# Background Image

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.asset(
          'assets/logo/greenframe.png',
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
...
```

I'm using this code for using a background image on my app. It is a rectangle frame. It works okay with my Redmi Note 8 screen but on another phone with a different size of the screen, it's not looking good. Not fitting the screen. Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try with BoxFit.cover

Comment: I edit question with 2 Screenshots. I described wrongly my problem. It is not auto scaling.

Comment: I mean my app is not respective to device's screen size.

Comment: Did you try with other BoxFit options ?

Comment: Not only my background image. This problem about all of my buttons, text. I think i shoud find a solution for respective app for all screen sizes.

Comment: How did you set the height and width of your buttons? If you are setting hard-coded values it'll be a problem. Set the size based on screen size

Comment: minWidth, height    How can i set the size based on screen size ? I literally open 25 chrome tabs for answer.

Comment: Okay i figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I set the size based on screen size?

You can use `MediaQuery.of(context).size` to get a responsive design for all screen sizes. For example, defining the size of the icon button will look like this:

```
     IconButton(
        iconSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.03, // Here!
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
      ),
```

Read more from [here](https://medium.com/tagmalogic/widgets-sizes-relative-to-screen-size-in-flutter-using-mediaquery-3f283afc64d6).